# Top margin not working from design view in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In XML in the design view, the place where we can give the constraint margin does not work in the case of Top/Bottom margin but works in start and end.

Having to give the margin manually in XML.

Could you point me to where to file a bug report regarding Android Studio IDE errors?

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111, built on February 2, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: idv.freddie.plugin.decompiler (0.7.0), com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.5.0), dev.polek.adbwifi (1.2.4), org.exbin.deltahex.intellij (0.2.5), name.kropp.intellij.makefile (211.7628.1), Dart (211.7798), wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.2), org.jetbrains.kotlin (211-1.6.10-release-923-AS7442.40), io.flutter (64.1.2), com.developerphil.adbidea (1.6.4), com.squareup.sqldelight (1.5.3), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
```

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong?" hard to say when you don't show us your code

Comment: It's a ide error .let me add the relevant pictures then

Comment: It would be more useful if you pasted an XML that can reproduce this error; this would rule out a potential error on your end.

Comment: Any view with a bottom and top margin inside a constraint layout .. not being able to set it in design view.. working in arctic fox